# How to index a media conversion url in Algolia in Laravel

Tags: laravel, algolia

I'm trying to index the url but I'm getting `null` in algolia. When I check in the tinker I get the url is not null. How can I ensure I get the url created from the conversion. Below is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

class Blog extends Model implements HasMedia
{
  use HasFactory;
  use InteractsWithMedia;
  use Searchable;

  protected $appends = ['small_thumb_url'];

  public function toSearchableArray()
  {
    return [
      'title' => $this->title,
      'slug' => $this->slug,
      'body' => $this->body,
      'small_thumb_url' => $this->small_thumb_url,
    ];
  }

  public function registerMediaCollections(): void
  {
    $this
      ->addMediaCollection('blog_main_photo')
      ->withResponsiveImages();
  }

  public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
  {
    $this->addMediaConversion('small_thumb')
      ->width(52)
      ->height(52);
  }

  // accessors
  public function getSmallThumbUrlAttribute()
  {
    $file = $this->getMedia('blog_main_photo')->last();

    if ($file) {
      return $file->getUrl('small_thumb');
    }
  }
}
```